# how to install devise 2.1.0 ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rubygems

I tried to install the same why that I installed 1.1.rc0 but i get the msg when i write the code

```
rails generate devise_install
Could not find generator devise_install.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
rails generate devise:install
```